# NSNumberFormatter and decimalSeparator issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I encountered the following problem while using `NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(String)` in Swift. 
I passed a float value to it separated by "." It worked perfectly on the simulator. But on a device I kept getting optional unwrapping error. I fixed it by using "," as a separator when running on a device. The device and the simulator run the same version of iOS (8.0.3). Can anyone explain what this difference is caused by?

P.S.:- Yes, I can manually set the decimal separator. Just curious why it's different on device/simulator by default?

Comment: Different regional/language settings in the Simulator and the real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal separator will be set according to your local language settings.
 Since you seem to have different decimal separators you will probably have different regional settings.